# Stack Overflow Jobs Easy Apply Submit does nothing

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I've filled out all required fields and attached my resume but when I hit Submit it takes me to the top of the page immediately with no feedback.  Checking under Applications my submission is not there.

This looks like a bug.  There is no feedback on the Easy Apply page that anything is wrong.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and see if there are any HTTP errors or any errors in the Network tab. See if you get a response in the Network tab and examine it.

Comment: No errors show up in the Network tab